# How to apply \usepackage[french]{babel} to marginnote in a tufte-book document

Tags: bibliographies, tufte, marginnote, babel-french

I use the {tufte-book}documentclass and I write my document in french language with usepackage[french]{babel}. Unfortunatly the margin notes and the bibliography references remains in english, as well as the formatting of the legends of the figures and tables. Does anybody could help me to apply the french langage on all the document ?

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{sample-handout}

\end{document}
```

This is an example of the problem above. You can see in the fourth note that there is a "and" in place of "et" and the word "edition" in place of "édition" :

[image]

Comment: Did you try specifying the `french` option with the document class rather than with `babel` (as should be)?

Comment: Please provide something that is self contained and actually show your problem.

Comment: Also please explain what you mean by ` bibliography references remains in english` bibtex styles are not know to support babel, so they are mainly in english. You miht want to have a loot at `biblatex` instead.

Comment: As mentioned `plainnat` is english only. You will need to find a style that supports `french` and supports `natbib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution !! I have to use the bibliographystyle{plain-fr}